# Create a new column from a conditional contents of two other columns in same row

Tags: r

Suppose I have dataset mtcars.

Suppose I want to create a new column called mtcars$newcol based on the lower value in each row of mtcars$gear and mtcars$cars.

```
head(mtcars)

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

What I want is :

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newcol
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    4 
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    4 
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4    3
```

Note that the value in newcol is the lower of the gear and carb row.

Comment: `pmin` is your friend, whether `transform(mtcars, newcol = pmin(gear,carb))` or `dplyr::mutate(mtcars, newcol = pmin(gear,carb))` or `mtcars$newcol <- pmin(mtcars$gear,mtcars$carb)`. Welcome to R!

Answer (score -1):

```
mtcars %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(newcol = min(gear, carb))
```

Comment: when there is a vectorized way to do things in R, never ever ever use `rowwise`; its existence is undeniable in some use-cases, but its use here is not right (and it performs poorly with larger data). Take a cue from my comment in the question itself and remove `rowwise` and replace `min` with `pmin`.